# Devise: undefined method `user_signed_in?' for ApplicationController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm getting the above error with Rails 3.1.1 and Ruby 1.9.2.  I've spent the last hour looking and the main things I've found were:

1. `clear_helpers` in ApplicationController can cause the helpers to not load.  My code isn't using that and I don't believe the gems I've installed are either.
2. Missing `devise_for` in routes.rb.  I have `devise_for :users`
3. Missing 'database_authenticatable' in my Users model.  I have in my users.rb :

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
4. My behavior matches exactly what's described in [this email thread](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/e87dd5d00ce0217c) except `signed_in? :user` doesn't work for me either.  However, `Devise.mappings` does show the user mapping.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?  Even a hack for current_user would help me greatly as I have to get some functionality running ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm marking this as a community wiki since the solution is trivial.

I was calling debugger (which I used to check `current_user` with the following code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  debugger
  filter {|c| Authorization.current_user = c.current_user}
end
```

Rails makes the session and request objects available to instances of controllers.  That debugger is called in the context of `self == ApplicationController` when it should be `self == #<MainController...>`.

Long story short, make sure you're not trying to call it within a controller *definition* but within the controller *instance*.

Answer (score 1):

Number 3 strikes me as odd. Is your model file named users.rb? Is your class declaration `Users < ActiveRecord::Base`? If so, change them to the below.

users.rb => user.rb

`User < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: It's actually user.rb and that was a typo on my part.  Good eye, though.  It actually was working and I was calling `current_user` and `user_signed_in?` in the wrong context

Comment: See my answer above.  I was calling it in the declaration of a controller instead of within an instance of a controller.