# undefined method `user_signed_in?' for ApplicationController:Class, Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The following code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  if user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

yields this error:

```
undefined method `user_signed_in?' for ApplicationController:Class, Devise
```

I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760784/devise-undefined-method-user-signed-in-for-applicationcontrollerclass) but I don't know what he means by instance of the application controller vs. definition of the application controller.  I have devise_for :users set up in the config/routes.rb file, am not using clear_helpers, and have :database_authenticatable in my user.rb file.  This if statement functions just fine if it's in an action in a different controller.  Why is it not working here?  Do I need to pass the devise helper in somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's saying call the function using the controller class definition itself, not an instance of the controller class.  In the code `self == ApplicationController` he is comparing `self` to the reference of the class definition `ApplicationController` rather than to a specific instance (or object) of `ApplicationController`.

In this case, the post is essentially saying to call the `debugger` function within a method of the controller and not just somewhere in the definition of the controller.

As the post mentions, you should be calling user_signed_in? within the context of an *instance*, not the definition.  So put it in a method to be used for a before filter or something.  For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def find_user_name
     if user_signed_in?
        return user.user_name
     end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Still a little confused.  When you say "call it", you mean debugger right?  How does this relate to where I should be putting my if statement?

Comment: Yes, in this case "call it" refers to the debugger. I've updated my answer in regards to your other question.

Comment: Updated the question to be more descriptive.  Devise seems to be working mostly fine.