# undefined method `user_signed_in?' for ApplicationController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to call user_signed_in? method on ApplicationController. But throw me that error.

I can use this method on another controller but this.
I've tried to put 
`before_action :current_user, unless: :devise_controller?` at the begining of the class but still not working.

I'm currently using rails 5.1.3 and Ruby 2.6.6
What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306185/undefined-method-user-signed-in-for-applicationcontrollerclass-devise

Comment: No. I’ve tried that too and I don’t know from where can inherit that method.

Comment: What is that you are actually trying to do? If you are trying to lock down your application and require authentication you would use `before_action :authenticate_user!` and then call `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!` to whitelist the routes that don't require authentication. Calling `current_user` in a `before_action` callback will do absolutely nothing as it has no side effects.

Comment: I want to get the current user, if there is any, to get their info in all current pages.